# Mask 2 df by columns position

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mask

I would like to mask a df using another one regardless the name of the columns, but considering only their positions. 
For example, given these 2 df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'D': [10,20,0], 'E': [0, 30, 10], 'F': [0, 0, 10]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1], 'C': [1, 1, 1], 'E': [1, 1, 1]})
```

and using this `mask`:

```
mask = (df != 0)
```

I would like:

```
     A    C    E
0  NaN  1.0  1.0
1  NaN  NaN  1.0
2  1.0  NaN  NaN
```

Where `D` masks `A`, `E`(of the first df) masks `C` and `F` masks `E`(of the second df).

I can do this removing columns names:

```
df.columns = [''] * len(df.columns)
mask = (df != 0)
df2.columns = [''] * len(df2.columns)
dfn = df2.mask(mask)
```

But is there a better way? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, is possible convert boolean DataFrame to boolean 2d array:

```
mask = (df != 0).values
dfn = df2.mask(mask)
print (dfn)

     A    C    E
0  NaN  1.0  1.0
1  NaN  NaN  1.0
2  1.0  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Give me 10 mins to accept the answer :)